# How can i implement signalR_netCore method in flutter

Tags: node.js, asp.net, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I want to connect my flutter app with signal R

this is the code of dependencies:

```
import 'package:signalr_netcore/signalr_client.dart';


final serverUrl = "192.168.10.50:51001";

final hubConnection = HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl(serverUrl).build();

final hubConnection.onclose( (error) => print("Connection Closed"));
```

how can implement it in my application to be able to use some classes??